# Build, using Shapeless, generic default instances for case classes with parameters defining a common createValue method

Tags: scala, shapeless, path-dependent-type, singleton-type

I'm trying to achieve the following - and using shapeless seems like a good path.

Given the current class model:

```
import shapeless._

object ShapelessTest {
  case class Definition[T](id: String) extends Typeable[T] {
    type V = Value[T]

    override def cast(t: Any): Option[T] = createValue(t.asInstanceOf[Option[T]]).value

    override def describe: String = s"$id"

    def createValue(value: Option[T]): V =
      Value[T](this, value)
  }

  case class Value[T](definition: Definition[T], value: Option[T])

  val DefA: Definition[Int] = Definition[Int]("defA")
  val DefB: Definition[String] = Definition[String]("defB")

  case class Instance(valA: DefA.V,
                      valB: DefB.V)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val Empty: Instance = Instance(
       DefA.createValue(None),
       DefB.createValue(None)
     )
    println(s"Empty manual: $Empty")

    val emptyHl = Generic[Instance].from(DefA.createValue(None) :: DefB.createValue(None) :: HNil)
    println(s"Empty hlist: $emptyHl")
  }
}
```

I can create an empty instance as the `Empty` instance, by manually invoking the `createValue` methods on the correct Definitions, or by converting an HList using shapeless.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to programmatically create an `Empty` instance for every class having fields of type `Value`.

In other words, I'd like to be able to invoke

```
val Empty: Instance = empty[Instance]
```

and have the same result of the `emptyHl` or `Empty` instances.

This seems similar to the "8.3 Random Value Generator" example in the shapeless guide, but instead of generating random numbers, using functions for every type present in the case class, I'm trying to materialize the concrete `Definition` type for every parameter, and invoke the `createValue(None)` method on it.

I've been trying quite a bit without success.

Using a `hlist.Mapper` with a `Poly1` defined over a `Typeable`, I'm able to get a list of the parameters, but I'm not able to invoke any methods on the typeable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

---

`Update 9 Apr`

I was able to come up with a very convoluted solution - unfortunately a lot of casting but does the job.

I would like to iterate over this and make it better. I tried using the `natMapper: NatTRel` but I wasn't able to make it work over Singleton Types.
I'm sure this can be made a lot better though! Any suggestion is welcome.

```scala
import shapeless.ops.hlist
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Comapped, Reify}
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, HNil}

object ShapelessTest2 {

  case class Definition[T](id: String) {
    type V = Value[this.type]

    def createValue(value: Option[T]) =
      new Value[this.type] {
        type NT = T
        override val valueT: Option[T] = value
        override val attrDef: Definition.this.type = Definition.this
      }
  }

  trait Value[D] {
    type NT
    val attrDef: D
    val valueT: Option[NT]
  }

  object DefA extends Definition[Int]("defA")
  object DefB extends Definition[Int]("defB")
  object DefC extends Definition[String]("defC")

  case class Instance(valA: DefA.V,
                      valB: DefB.V,
                      valC: DefC.V)

  // Compile safe
  val Inst1: Instance = Instance(
    DefA.createValue(Some(1)),
    DefB.createValue(Some(2)),
    DefC.createValue(Some("2"))
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def empty[A <: Product] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

    class PartiallyApplied[A <: Product] {
      def apply[
          V <: HList,
          DL <: HList,
          RDL <: HList,
          H <: Definition[_],
          T <: HList
      ]()(
          implicit
          gen: Generic.Aux[A, V],
          comapped: Comapped.Aux[V, Value, DL],
          reify: Reify.Aux[DL, RDL],
          isHCons: hlist.IsHCons.Aux[RDL, H, T],
      ): A = {
        def getEmpties[L](list: RDL): V = {
          val hlist = list match {
            case HNil => HNil
            case _ => list.head.createValue(None) :: getEmpties(list.tail.asInstanceOf[RDL])
          }
          hlist.asInstanceOf[V]
        }

        val empties = getEmpties(reify.apply())
        gen.from(empties)
      }
    }

    val emptyInstance = empty[Instance]()
    println(s"Empty valA: ${emptyInstance.valA.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valA.valueT}")
    println(s"Empty valB: ${emptyInstance.valB.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valB.valueT}")
    println(s"Empty valC: ${emptyInstance.valC.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valC.valueT}")
  }
}
```

Correctly prints

```
Empty valA: Definition(defA) - None
Empty valB: Definition(defB) - None
Empty valC: Definition(defC) - None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you somehow abuse `Typeable`. The idea of using `Typeable` is to have type-safe cast. But you come back to `asInstanceOf`.

`Typeable` is a type class. So you should use your `Definition` as a type class. Make `DefA`, `DefB`, ... implicit.

```
implicit val DefA: Definition[Int] = Definition[Int]("defA")
implicit val DefB: Definition[String] = Definition[String]("defB")

def empty[A <: Product] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

class PartiallyApplied[A <: Product] {
  def apply[Vs <: HList, L <: HList, Ds <: HList]()(implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, Vs],
    comapped: Comapped.Aux[Vs, Value, L],
    liftAll: LiftAll.Aux[Definition, L, Ds],
    natMapper: NatTRel[Ds, Definition, Vs, Value],
  ): A = {
    object createValueNatTransform extends (Definition ~> Value) {
      override def apply[T](definition: Definition[T]): Value[T] =
        definition.createValue(None)
    }

    gen.from(natMapper.map(createValueNatTransform, liftAll.instances))
  }
}

val Empty: Instance = empty[Instance]() 
// Instance(Value(Typeable[defA],None),Value(Typeable[defB],None))
```

---

Macro working with your original code

```
def empty[A]: A = macro emptyImpl[A]

def emptyImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val typA = weakTypeOf[A]
  val trees = typA.decls.filter(_.asTerm.isVal).map(_.infoIn(typA) match {
    case TypeRef(pre, _, _) => q"${pre.termSymbol}.createValue(_root_.scala.None)"
  })
  q"new $typA(..$trees)"
}

val Empty: Instance = empty[Instance]

//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion App.empty[App.Instance]
//Warning:scalac: new App.Instance(DefA.createValue(_root_.scala.None),
//                                 DefB.createValue(_root_.scala.None))

// Instance(Value(Typeable[defA],None),Value(Typeable[defB],None))
```

---

Regarding your new code make `Value` covariant and use `Mapper` (for properly defined `Poly`) instead of `NatTRel` or runtime recursion

```
trait Value[+D] {
  type NT
  val attrDef: D
  val valueT: Option[NT]
}

object createValuePoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[D <: Definition[T] with Singleton, T](implicit
    ev: D <:< Definition[T]): Case.Aux[D, Value[D]] = at(_.createValue(None))
}

def empty[A <: Product] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

class PartiallyApplied[A <: Product] {
  def apply[
      V <: HList,
      DL <: HList,
  ]()(
      implicit
      gen: Generic.Aux[A, V],
      comapped: Comapped.Aux[V, Value, DL],
      reify: Reify.Aux[DL, DL],
      mapper: Mapper.Aux[createValuePoly.type, DL, V]
  ): A = gen.from(mapper(reify()))
}

val emptyInstance = empty[Instance]()
println(s"Empty valA: ${emptyInstance.valA.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valA.valueT}") 
//Empty valA: Definition(defA) - None
println(s"Empty valB: ${emptyInstance.valB.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valB.valueT}") 
//Empty valB: Definition(defB) - None
println(s"Empty valC: ${emptyInstance.valC.attrDef} - ${emptyInstance.valC.valueT}") 
//Empty valC: Definition(defC) - None
```

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, this put in the right direction!
I still have a problem when dealing with definitions with the same type, let's say `val DefA: Definition[Int] = Definition[Int]("defA");
  val DefB: Definition[Int] = Definition[Int]("defB")` these are clearly two different singleton types, but they confuse the compiler during implicit resolution. Could a `Witness` be useful in this case?

Comment: @IacopoPace Among what you've just written there are no singleton types, it's just `Definition[Int]`. `case class Instance(valA: DefA.V, valB: DefB.V)` is just `case class Instance(valA: Value[Int], valB: Value[String])`, there is no information about `DefA`, `DefB` here, `Value[Int]`, `Value[String]` don't "remember" that they were `DefA.V`, `DefB.V`. It seems you want to work with `case class Instance...` definition as AST, this can be done with macros.

Comment: That totally makes sense, you're right!
Do you think that reworking this by using something like `object DefA extends Definition[Int]("defA")` and subsequently `case class Instance(valA: DefA.V)` would help?

Comment: Thanks to your pointers I was able to make it work - I updated the question.
I would love to make the implementation better, any suggestion is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: @IacopoPace By the way, I added macro working with your original code.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do could be achieved much easier without using `Typeable` at all (and BTW, `Typeable[T]` should be used as a type class and not a mixin). In ggeneral, pattern for deriving type classes with shapeless looks like this:

```
import shapeless._

trait Empty[A] {
  def createValue(): A
}
object Empty {
  // summoning method
  def apply[T](implicit empty: Empty[T]): T = empty.createValue()

  // implicits for HNil and HCons build HList if we provide the right implicits

  implicit val emptyHNil: Empty[HNil] = () => HNil

  implicit def emptyHCons[H, T](
    implicit 
    head: Empty[H],
    tail: Empty[T]
  ): Empty[H :: T] = () => head.createValue() :: tail.createValue()

  // Generic will translate it HList into Product type

  implicit def emptyProduct[T, Rep](
    implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, Rep],
    empty: Empty[Rep]
  ): Empty[T] = () => gen.from(empty.createValue())

  // if you need default instances accessible everywhere without import put them here
}
```

used as

```
case class Instance(int: Int, string: String)
implicit int: Empty[Int] = () => 0
implicit int: Empty[String] = () => ""
Empty[Instance].createValue[Instance] // Instance(0, "")
```

In your case you would have to make `Value[T]`s available in implicit scope and derive `Value[Instance]` from smaller values (like in `Empty` example above). How you provide basic `Value` instances in implicit scope is up to you: you can put them into companion object, or define manually or derive from other types that are already in the implicit scope.

Long story short, what you want should be possible but you have to put things into implicit scope first.

Comment: Hey Mateusz, I'm still trying to wrap my head around shapeless and most of its concepts, so thanks for pointing out the usage of Typeable! I tried the approach you suggested, which is very similar to the one used for random generator on the shapeless guide, but it doesn't take into consideration that my generator of empty values must be based on a method present on the Definition type. The poly approach suggested by Dmytro above seems promising but I still have a couple of problems there. Thanks! :)